# как строку разбить на массив в запросе mysql (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Допустим есть строка с названиями, записанные через ",".

```
let nameStr="name1,name2,name3".
```

Как написать select запрос используя эту строку?

Есть таблица

```
+---------------+-------+-----+
|     name      | value | ... |
+---------------+-------+-----+
| name1         |     1 |     |
| name2         |     2 |     |
| name3         |     3 |     |
| name4         |     4 |     |
| name5         |     5 |     |
| name6         |     6 |     |
+---------------+-------+-----+
```

нужно вывести в результате те имена и значение, которые есть в строке

Comment: Где вам нужно запрос сделать? Если на Node.JS можете использовать библиотеку Express и там делать запросы. Вот тут полная документация https://expressjs.com/

Comment: @SerikShaikamalov, нафига тащить web-framework, если вопрос про sql?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mysql = require("mysql")

var names = "name1,name2,name3".split(",")

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "some_user",
  password: "some_passowrd",
  database: "some_db",
})

con.connect(err => { if (err) throw err })

con.query("select * from SomeTable where name in (?)", [names], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.table(rows)
})

con.end()
```

Comment: Эм.. А где тут вообще подзапрос?

Comment: а в mssql  это будет работать?

Comment: @asfd, понятия не имею. Очевидно, что там другой пакет нужен, но он тоже что-то такое должен уметь.